# Null variable issues errors while trying to repurpose a bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am a little stuck trying to compile a bot using visual studio.  Since the bot can't be used anymore I thought I would be able to re-purpose it.  So I used dotpeek on the executable and tried testing to see if it would compile again. So far no errors but the one for time. I want to assume that I don't have the right source files but even when visual studio and dotpeek are synced for Symbol use the error still occurs.

```
public static List<string> DecryptLicense(string path, string key)
    {
      string s1 = File.ReadAllText(path);
      while (s1.Length % 4 != 0)
        s1 += "=";
      string str1 = Decrypter.Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(s1)).Caesar((short) -8), key);
      string s2 = str1.Substring(0, 15);
      string str2 = str1.Substring(15);
      string format = "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss";
      // ISSUE: variable of the null type
      __Null local = null;
      DateTime exact = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, format, (IFormatProvider) local);
      if (Global.GetNistTime() > exact)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("License expired (" + exact.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss UTC+0") + "). Press one key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(0);
      }
      List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
      while (str2 != "")
      {
        string str3 = str2.Substring(0, 40);
        str2 = str2.Substring(40);
        stringList.Add(str3);
      }
      return stringList;
    }
```

I've tried changing the __Null into a var, but I believe it is a formatting problem when it tries to change using IFormatProvider.  Any insight on how this can be resolved is appreciated.

Here is the instance of the other part where the error occurs for reference:

```
 public static string SleepTime
    {
      get
      {
        return Global._sleepTime;
      }
      set
      {
        Global._sleepTime = value;
        string[] strArray = value.Split(' ');
        for (int index = 0; index < strArray.Length; ++index)
        {
          string s1 = strArray[index].Split('-')[0];
          string s2 = strArray[index].Split('-')[1];
          DateTime exact1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "HH:mm", (IFormatProvider) null);
          string format = "HH:mm";
          __Null local = null;
          DateTime exact2 = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, format, (IFormatProvider) local);
          Global.SleepTimes.Add(new DateTime[2]
          {
            exact1,
            exact2
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Since it's only ever assigned `null` once and never again, and it's only read a single time, why don't you simply remove it?  You can't change `__Null` to `var` because a `var` declaration must be able to implicitly determine the type.  `null` does not have an implicit type.

Comment: The problem also persists in another area as well, the program is able to be set on a sleep timer in which it will become inactive keep checking the time until it is ready to run again.  I thought a fix in this location will help me fix the error in the other location as the program is made to run 24/7.

Comment: If you have another problem, ask another question.

Comment: Okay, and what is stopping you from making the same change in both locations?  They look nearly identical.

Comment: You mean deleting the null or local?  Because local then wouldn't be given a variable type.

Comment: Going back to my first comment, remove the `local` variable *entirely* and replace instances of it with `null`.  It simply isn't used.  So remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the declaration of `local` entirely.  It's never used for anything, so spending any time determining its type is wasted.

The `__Null` type was likely inserted simply to obfuscate the code and hinder any attempts to decompile the code.

Replace any instances of `local` with `null`, as in:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "HH:mm", (IFormatProvider) local);
                                                    ↓ ↓
DateTime.ParseExact(s1, "HH:mm", (IFormatProvider) null);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I am able to work on the program again, I never thought that anything would have hindered decompiling but the rest of the code is intact.

Comment: Yeah, look up obfuscators.  Visual Studio comes with a free one you can play with.  Try making a "hello world" app, obfuscate it, then attempt to decompile it.

Comment: I'll take a look into that, seems like there is a lot to learn from it.